# HTML/CSS - Angular material custom dialog

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, tailwind-css

I'm trying in every way to create a custom angular material dialog with a custom header using some `css/scss` and tailwindcss framework. The desired effect would be that of the figure below.

**desired-effect**

[image: desired-effect]

After many attempts, I am stuck at the following result:

**current-effect**

[image: current-effect]

I have trouble filling the white part under the header and the material icon with the yellow background-color. Below is my html/css code:

CODE:

```html
<div class="w-full bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900">

    <div class="edit-dialog-header">
        <div class="edit-dialog-header-title pl-5 pr-10 pt-4 uppercase w-max" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start">
            <div class="font-bold">Dialog title</div>
            <span class="edit-dialog-button-exit">
                <button class="p-1" [mat-dialog-close]
                        matTooltip="Close"
                        mat-icon-button>
                    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="edit-dialog-header-subtitle pl-5 pr-5 uppercase">Dialog subtitle</div>

        <div class="grid justify-items-center edit-dialog-header-footer">
            <mat-icon class="material-icons-round badge w-10 h-10">link</mat-icon>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div> Some Content ... </div>
</div>
```

```css
.mat-dialog-container {
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.mat-dialog-content {
    margin: 20px;
}

.edit-dialog-header {
    background-color: #929aa0;

    .edit-dialog-header-footer {
        background: #ffffff;
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ffffff 50%, rgba(146, 154, 160, 1) 50%);

        mat-icon {
            font-size: 20px;
        }

    }

    .edit-dialog-header-title, .edit-dialog-header-subtitle {
        color: #fbfbfd;
    }

    .edit-dialog-header-title {
        font-size: x-large;
    }

    .edit-dialog-header-subtitle {
        font-size: medium;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .edit-dialog-button-exit {
        button {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            border: none;
            background-color: #929aa0;

            mat-icon {
                color: #fbfbfd;
            }
        }
    }
}

.badge {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fbfbfd;
    background: #929aa0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fill in that white space under the header ??
Thank you everyone

Comment: Just want to confirm what are you trying to set to white as in your css it states `.edit-dialog-header-footer` `background: #ffffff; ` when looking at your desired effect, I don't see what that's suppose to represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `z-index: 10` in your css class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).